# Chatter feed auto refresh

Tags: apex, after-trigger

So i have used a trigger to delete the Chatter Post but unless the chatter feed is refreshed the latest update will not be visible.
Is there any way to refresh the chatter feed when the record is deleted through Trigger

Answer (score 0):

You cannot auto refresh chatter feed in salesforce, Kindly review and vote for this [feature](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZHwUAN/chatter-stream-or-ticker).

Thanks